# I want to retry test cases that throw Null point exception only , is there any way to do that?

Tags: testng, retry-logic

When I give the retry method to some selected test cases, all such test cases will retry for the given amount of times, but I want to retry test cases only if there is a NUll Point exception, is there any way to do it with testNG?

Comment: You should aim for deterministic tests.

Answer (score 0):

Define `RetryAnalyzer` where you would check for `Throwable` actual type like:

```java
public class MyRetry implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    private int retryCount = 0;
    private static final int maxRetryCount = 3;

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        if(result.getThrowable() instanceof NullPointerException 
          && retryCount < maxRetryCount){
            retryCount++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```java
@Test(retryAnalyzer = MyRetry.class)
public class MyTest {

    Object o;


    public void testRetryNPE(){
        o.toString();
    }

    public void testNoNPE(){
        int i = 1/0;
    }

}
```